# Taking too much time to set lable's rotation and offset Using core plot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

In my application, I am using core plot library for chart, I am using DatePlot example from that.

While i use two statement as below

```
x.labelRotation             = M_PI / 4;
x.labelOffset = 10.0;
```

Its taking too much time to load graph around 1.5 - 2 minute, And if I comment this both line its loading time is okay and just loading within 5-10 seconds.

Any idea how can i fix this ? Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Check the axis labeling policy and related properties (e.g., `majorIntervalLength`). The default settings will create thousands of ticks and labels when using a typical time scale on the axis. This can take a long time to generate and render.